# regex few blocks exact length

Tags: regex

I want to match 5 to 20 character with regex.
I try to use below regular expression for my checking.

```
/^[a-zA-Z][\w]{5,20}$/
```

It's work, but the problem of length it match 6 to 21 character.

```
(^[a-zA-Z][\w]){4,20}$
```

I also try this but it don't work.

Please anyone help me to match exact length of regex.

Comment: second regex i use this
(^[a-zA-Z][\w]){5,20}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your capturing group is expecting TWO characters:
`[a-zA-Z]` and `[\w]`, that's two letters.

So your first attempt actually did this:

- match [a-zA-Z] once
- match [\w] once
- match the previous matches 5 - 20 times
- Inevitably, you always had 1 more match than expected

Capture only one character, and iterate it 5-20 times.
Have you tried:
`^([a-zA-Z]{5,20})$` ?
OR
`^(\w{5,20})$` ?

You're almost there, you just need to make a single range of characters (in square brackets) not two.

Comment: Be more specific: what is your input, what result are you expecting?

Comment: string start with a-zA-Z but letter char can digit or a-zA-Z. THanks

Comment: so the string MUST start with a LETTER, but the 4-19 characters that follow can be ANYTHING?

Comment: Then you want `^([\da-zA-Z]{5,20})$`     
Please update your question with this information, as it was not very clear.

Comment: I thing it allow digits on first character.right and thanks again for replay .

Comment: Sorry, once again misinterpreted:
`^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]{4,19})$`
that allows only a letter at first, then only letters and digits, up to 20 characters in length, and minimally 4

Comment: I create a function for do this job and pass the length in function parameter . So I need the exact length of the char . right .
THANKS AGAIN

Comment: If you need the length of the string (or returned match), that's another question. Do some tests, try things out. And post a relevant question should you have difficulties.

Comment: I have a regular expression with few grouping blocks for matching my string.

I want to set whole expression length on last ok

   ** /^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]{5,10}$/**

I want to set whole length 5 to 10 char.

but it allow 7 to 13 char. so how to fix the length problem .PLz

match string like 

 **a2art**        
 **T9aDtYU**          
 **e5art**           
 **T9aILGre**

Comment: It's the **same** issue as before. Review the many good answers provided to your original issue. And please, test things out on http://regex101.com

Answer (score 2):

The Quantifier is only applied to the [\w]. So this expects exactly one letter character and then 5-20 whitespace characters.

I assume you want 5-20 characters that can be either a letter a-z or a whitespace. You need to group these together in square brackets and then apply the quantifier:

```
^[a-zA-Z\W]{5,20}$
```

So, I understand, you want a string that has 5-20 characters, starts with a letter and then only has letters and digits. You would write it like that:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{4,19}$
```

This expects first a letter and then 4-19 letters or digits.

BTW: https://regex101.com/ is a great site to test regular expressions and get an explanation what they are doing.

Comment: if i use this it allow digit on first character. right ... thanks

Comment: props for regex101  
can't live without it!

Answer (score 2):

`/^[a-zA-Z][\w]{5,20}$/` means:

- a character from a to z in lower or upper case
- 5 to 20 word characters

That sums up to 6 to 21 characters in total.

---

I suppose you want `/^[a-zA-Z][\w]{4,19}$/`:

- a character from a to z in lower or upper case
- 4 to 19 word characters

That sums up to 5 to 20 characters in total.

Comment: I also try this. But i make a function for it and pass the length parameter.
So i need the exact length of char.
If there are any way to do this ?
THANKS

Comment: @ABHIJIT could you decrease the length parameter by one before inserting it into the regular expression? I'm thinking of `myregexp = "/^[a-zA-Z][\w]{4,"+(length-1)+"}$/";` (the code depends on the programming language, of course).

Comment: **THANKS YOU SO MUCH**